# How to create space between UINavigationBar and top of UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview, swift

I have a UITableView in my storyboard. I put a navigation bar at the top of the view. However the title seems to close to the top of the view near the time and battery. Is there any way to create spacing like in the view to the left of that one? I tried simply dragging the navigation bar down but it seems pinned to the top of the view. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using autolayout (which I very much recommend), you are just missing a Vertical Space Constraint between your container view and your table view.

See the size inspector (as shown below) for a list of constraints on a UI element, or browse your Document Outline for missing constraints.

[image: Size inspector]

Comment: I can not use auto layout for the navigation bar. I select the nav bar and click the pin button and it does not let me set any constraints.